# Get the vertex with highest degree of a large graph in GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

In Spark GraphX, I use `graph.degrees.reduce( (a,b) => if (a._2 > b._2) a else b )` to get the highest-degree vertex in a graph called [LiveJournal](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/soc-LiveJournal1.html) [4,847,571 nodes, 68,993,773 edges].


I'm writing an algorithm for my graph analytic study. The LiveJournal graph I'm running the algorithm on is very large, my machine takes forever to execute the reduce phase! So I was wondering if there is a more efficient and less time-consuming way to get the same result of the line above.

Comment: probably going to have a hard time beating that, its what graphx was designed for and your code is right out of the graphx guide

Comment: While I can't speak to this specific algorithm, I do know that certain "stock" `GraphX` algorithms are not very efficient. For more on that, see here: http://www.frankmcsherry.org/graph/scalability/cost/2015/01/15/COST.html

Answer (score 1):

On my MacBook (8 cores) it takes less than a minute to run. I needed to allow 4G of driver memory running in local mode.

I start spark-shell like this:

```
bin/spark-shell --driver-memory 4g
```

Then run the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, "soc-LiveJournal1.txt")
val output = graph.degrees.reduce( (a,b) => if (a._2 > b._2) a else b
```

Output looks like this:

```
scala> output
res0: (org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, Int) = (10009,22889)
```

Note: this is using Spark 1.6.1

Comment: I did the same with my 8 cores PC by assigning 6G of ram to the driver process in local mode. What I forgot to mention above is that I'm running my code from Eclipse (not spark-shell) both in local mode (local[*]) and standalone mode (I set up a 4 workers cluster and passed the spark://x.x.x.x:7077 parameter to the SparkConf of my code inside Eclipse). What I can't figure out is where to set the "--driver-memory" inside Eclipse! because I know I shouldn't set it through SparkConf (accord. to Spark documentation). Also, should I set the "executor.memory" arg for each of my workers? and plz how?

Comment: Not sure as don't use Eclipse much. Don't you have to create a run configuration and then enter the --driver-memory parameter in the VM arguments